# Websockets freezeing Firefox UI

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

When I press load more question [image]

My Firefox freezes for 3 seconds(can do nothing e.g. open a new tab). I've notice that Websocket connection is established. What is weird, is other similar functionalities works well e.g. when changes are made to an answer, loads changes very fast (it's also ws isn't it?).

Shouldn't it work in a more asynchronous manner? In a sense that UI doesn't freeze.

Win 7 64bit, FF 12.0.

Comment: Hmm... I don't experience the same behavior on FF12, Win7x64.

Comment: I should add that I have 30 questions (or more) per page. Also less popular tags loads faster and chrome doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a silly bug which was creating a large array when new questions arrived.  The latest version of Firefox didn't enjoy this much even though chrome had no problems.  This fix has been deployed.

Comment: Yay, works! ____